# If statement always returns true c#

Tags: c#, if-statement, boolean

When I run this statement I always get a return of true even if some of the bools return false. Any ideas on a fix?

```
public bool Enabled() {
          foreach (LinkIn link in linksIn) {
            if (link.source.amount < link.amount) {
              return false;
            }
          }
          //Not checking capacity correctly
          foreach (LinkOut link in linksOut) {
            if (link.target.Limited()
                && link.target.capacity < link.amount
                && link.target.amount + link.amount > link.target.capacity)
                {
                 return false;
                }
          }
          return true;
        }
```

The `link.target.Limited()` simply checks if a target has a capacity.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: you are using && so all the conditions have to be true in order to return false

Comment: The solution *might* be `if (link.target.Limited() && (link.target.capacity < link.amount || link.target.capacity < link.target.amount + link.amount))`, but without a specification I am just guessing. "If the target is Limited(), then fail if either we are larger than the capacity, or if there is not enough space in the target to add our amount". That means `if (link.target.Limited() && link.target.capacity < link.target.amount + link.amount)` would probably suffice. (BTW, if this answers the question, I'll post as an answer)

Comment: BTW, your statement "I always get a return of true even if some of the bools return false" is what the program states; as you have written your code, for at least one iteration all your boolean expressions must be true. You are probably being downvoted because your problem is not clearly stated.

Comment: @KenY-N Your changed of  <pre>    if (link.target.Limited() && link.target.capacity < link.target.amount + link.amount)     <code> worked, sorry for not stating my question clearly.

Comment: BTW, one must use backticks `\`my code\`` to format code in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to work out the requirements, I reckon that what you want is:

> If the target is Limited(), then fail if either we are larger than the capacity, or if there is not enough space in the target to add our amount

So, that would make the condition:

```
if (link.target.Limited()
 && (link.target.capacity < link.amount
       || link.target.amount + link.amount > link.target.capacity))
```

To be more symmetric, by swapping the LHS and RHS of the third expression this can be written as:

```
if (link.target.Limited()
 && (link.target.capacity < link.amount
  || link.target.capacity < link.target.amount + link.amount))
```

Now, we can further see that `link.target.capacity < link.amount` is true if and only if `link.target.capacity < link.target.amount + link.amount` is also true, so we can simplify to:

```
if (link.target.Limited()
 && link.target.capacity < link.target.amount + link.amount)
```